# I'm new to networking in C, and i need to send a string(char array) from command line arguments to a server

Tags: c, sockets, networking, command-line-arguments

However when i try to send command line argument, it is being sent to server but not displayed, on the other hand when I copy a hardcoded string to the msgBuffer and then send it ,it gets displayed on the server successfully. (see client code for example)

Here is my server code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int socket_id = 0, accept_socket = 0, n=1;
    int port_no;
    char msgBuff[256];
    char msgRecv[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;

    strcpy(msgBuff,"Hello World\n");

    socket_id = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(socket_id < 0){
        printf("Error retrieving socket.");
        exit(0);
    }

    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_address.sin_port = atoi(argv[1]);

    if(bind(socket_id, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) < 0){

        printf("Error binding socket.");
        exit(0);
    }


    if(listen(socket_id, 5) < 0){
        printf("Error listening to socket.");
    }

    while(1){
        accept_socket = accept(socket_id, NULL, NULL);
        n = read(accept_socket, msgRecv, 1024);
        msgRecv[n] = 0;

        if(n < 0){
            printf("error reading message");
    }

    printf("%s",msgRecv);
        write(accept_socket, msgBuff, strlen(msgBuff)); 
        close(accept_socket);       
    }
return 0;
}
```

to run server: ./server    port_number

to run client: ./client 127.0.0.1     port_number      message_to_be_sent

and here is the client code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int socket_id = 0, connect_status, n,len;
struct sockaddr_in serverDetail;
char msgRecv[512];
char msgBuff[2048];

strcpy(msgBuff, "xyz.com");               //THIS WORKS
    strcpy(msgBuff, argv[3]);                 //THIS DOESNT

socket_id = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if(socket_id < 0){
    printf("Error retrieving socket");
    exit(0);
}

serverDetail.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverDetail.sin_port = atoi(argv[2]);
serverDetail.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);

connect_status = connect(socket_id, (struct sockaddr*)&serverDetail, sizeof(serverDetail));

if(connect_status < 0 ){
    printf("Error connecting to server");
    exit(0);
}
write(socket_id , argv[3], 1024);

n = read(socket_id, msgRecv, sizeof(msgRecv));

if(n < 0){
    printf("Error in message reading");
    exit(0);
}

printf("%s",msgRecv);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only write in the client is `write(socket_id , argv[3], 1024);`, but I would think you want to write `msgBuff`.  You also might want to print out `argc` and all your `argv` values to make sure they are what you think they are.

Comment: I've tried that already and it wont work. if I just copy a hardcoded string in msgBuff, it works perfectly fine. But if I pass argv[3] to strcpy(), it dosent.

Comment: You also might want to print out argc and all your argv values to make sure they are what you think they are.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `argv[3]` is a *string*, i.e. it's a sequence of characters *terminated* by a `'\0'` character. If you unconditionally send `1024` bytes, you will most likely send way to much, leading to *undefined behavior* as you go out of bounds of the string.

I suggest you instead use `strlen` to send the exact number of characters in the string.

You also don't seem to terminate all strings in all cases that you receive.

Comment: Even when I do that, the case remains the same for hardcoded and command-line arguments.